# C++ Default constructor not available

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors, default-constructor

I'm currently learning C++ and reading through "C++ Primer 5th Edition". I just started learning about constructors and I'm having a bit of a problem that I can't figure out.

```
#ifndef SALES_DATA_H
#define SALES_DATA_H
#include <string>
struct Sales_data
{
    //default constructor
    Sales_data(const std::string &s, unsigned n, double p):
               bookNo(s), units_sold(n), revenue(p*n) { } 
    //new members: operations on Sales_data objects
    std::string isbn() const { return bookNo; }
    Sales_data& combine(const Sales_data&);
    double avg_price() const;
    //data members
    std::string bookNo;
    unsigned units_sold;
    double revenue;
};
```

I'm pretty sure that the default constructor I wrote is correct (considering it's the one written in the book), but obviously I'm missing something here. I don't see any syntax errors or anything and all of the built-in members are being initialized so I have no idea what's wrong.

**EDIT :**

I just found out that it's not my header file giving the error, it's actually my source file.  When I create a Sales_data object like:

```
Sales_data total;
```

it gives me the "No appropriate default constructor available" error.  I'm still unsure as to what's wrong considering the author gave three ways to write a default constructor, these are them:

```
struct Sales_data {
// constructors added
Sales_data() = default;   //Number 1
Sales_data(const std::string &s): bookNo(s) { }    //Number 2
Sales_data(const std::string &s, unsigned n, double p):    //Number 3
           bookNo(s), units_sold(n), revenue(p*n) { }
```

If those aren't default constructors, then what exactly are they/is their purpose?

Comment: I do believe you forgot to explain *what* the problem is

Comment: That's not a default constructor - default constructor either takes no parameters or has default values for all of them.

Comment: What was in that other header file ?

Comment: Show the line(s) where the problem occurs.

Comment: show the exact compile error

Comment: I hate when people start learning C++ And books suggest starting with structs ... i don't see any use for them in modern C++ programming

Comment: @AngryDuck And why is that?

Comment: Because it just seems as if they are only in the language for C compatibility just use a class, or an anonymous namespace if its just or variable declaration...

Comment: @AngryDuck wrong.. there are POD structs and polymorphic structs. This one is obviously not a POD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A default constructor is a constructor that can be called without passing any argument.

This means that it must take no parameters or that all of them must have a default value.

The default constructor is needed for example when you write

```
MyClass x;
```

because the compiler must be able to generate code to build such an object without any arguments.

Also standard containers may require a default constructor depending on how you use them: for example if you use `std::vector::resize` the library can be asked to increase the size of a vector containing your class instances, thus it must be able to create elements without providing any argument.

Comment: @JBL The default ctor is only generated if there are no user-defined ctors. This class has a user-defined ctor, so no default one.

Comment: The fact that s/he says s/he's pretty sure defined a default constructor made me think that there's confusion about what a default constructor is. BTW I cannot see anywhere in the code shown where a default constructor could be needed so clearly this is also not all the code.

Comment: @Angew Right, I forgot that, my mistake.

Comment: @Angew: Or when explicitly requested, see the `Sales_data() = default; ` example in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't related to default constructors. The problem indeed is in `Sales_data total;`. What's the book number, sales price and number sold for `total`? You must provide them when constructing `total`.

Comment: I don't want to paste the whole program (too much space) but the book number, sales price and number sold is initialized with user input during run-time.  So you're saying I would just have to initialize each member of the object in my source file? Doesn't that defeat the purpose of declaring a default constructor?

Comment: @Hysler: Normally, you'd first get the user input, and only then create the `Sates_data` object. Default constructors are sometimes useful if there is a reasonable default value. A `std::vector` starts empty, for instance. But your class does not appear to have a natural default value, so it shouldn't have a default constructor either.

Comment: Ahhh, okay, that makes sense now. Thanks for the help MSalters!

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of your class takes three parameters, those must be provided when you try to construct an object. Your current variable declaration doesn't provide any parameters:

```
Sales_data total;
```

Because there are no parameters provided, the compiler tries to use a constructor that doesn't take any parameters. Such a constructor is also called "default constructor". Your class doesn't have a constructor without parameters, so this doesn't work.

To use the existing constructor, you have to provide the parameters when you create the object:

```
Sales_data total("books", 28, 15.99);
```

Alternatively you could add a constructor to `Sales_data` that doesn't take any parameters (a default constructor), and initializes the class with some default values.